# Reverse case (Lowercase/Uppercase) of an input value character by character

Tags: javascript, html, string

By using one input text box and the input type allows only alphabets.The value entered is 'a' and it should be display outside the textbox as 'A'?

If we enter the alphabet small 'a' on input text then it will wanted to display capital 'A' on the outside of the box...
The following is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <!--<script type="text/javascript" href="check.js"></script>-->
      </head>
        <body>
          <input type="text">
             <script>
                function myFunction()
                {
                    var A = document.getElementById('input').value; 
                    console.log('alphabet'.toUpperCase());
                }
             </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You did not formulate a question. And your function `myFunction` is never called, in which your variable `A` is never used and in which you log a constant string.

Comment: @SaiKrishna doesn't my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

To show the input value with case reversed you should:

1. Call your function in the `onkeyup` event of your input to update the preview immediately with the inputted string.
2. And loop through your string and for each character test if it's in
   `uppercase` reverse it to `lowercase` or make it `uppercase` if it's
   `lowercase`.

Here's a Snippet DEMO:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var A = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0, len = A.length; i < len; i++) {
    var character = A[i];
    if (character == character.toLowerCase()) {
      // The character is lowercase
      output = output + character.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      // The character is uppercase
      output = output + character.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("preview").innerText = output;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" onkeyup="myFunction()" /><span id="preview"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an event for immediatly update the result, while writing.

```js
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if (!input.match(/^[a-z]*$/i)) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Wrong input';
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.split('').map(function (a) {
        return a.match(/[a-z]/)  ? a.toUpperCase() : a.toLowerCase();
    }).join('');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Its okay...suppose if we insert the element 'A' on the input text box then it will display small 'a' and vice-versa..

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseCase(str) {
    let newstr = str.split('');
    let newarr = [];
    //return newstr;
    for(i=0; i<newstr.length; i++) {
        if(newstr[i] == newstr[i].toLowerCase()){
            newarr.push(newstr[i].toUpperCase());
        }else 
        if(newstr[i] == newstr[i].toUpperCase()){
            newarr.push(newstr[i].toLowerCase());
        }
    } return newarr.join('');
}
console.log(reverseCase("Happy Birthday"))
```